# Error while installing express in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I already installed nodejs .I want to install expressjs using npm command.While installing I have some error.

The errors are:

```
D:\>cd expressfirstprogram

D:\expressfirstprogram>npm install express
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express"
npm ERR! node v7.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

npm ERR! unable to get local issuer certificate
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\expressfirstprogram\npm-debug.log

D:\expressfirstprogram>
```

can you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you notice the error message telling you that the connection was refused? If so, what did you do to determine if that was the case? I don't mean to be harsh or anything, but with the information you give us right now, it looks like you did not even look at the error.

Comment: I saw that connection refused and I dont know how to solve it..I disabled the proxy and tried again...but still error exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off ssl checking in your `.npmrc`

.npmrc file: 
`strict-ssl=false`

and then run `npm install express --save`

Link to the solution.
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9580#issuecomment-166605021

Comment: Great! Thumbs up if there is no issue.